# Only allow Document Sets in a Document Library (ie no Folders)

Tags: document-library, content-type, document-set

I'm exploring the use of Document Sets as a more managed approach to file handling (in the recordkeeping sense) in SharePoint.

The chief problem I have is that Document Sets are derived from Folders, and indeed it's possible to view Document Sets as a folder through Explorer View.  But if I create a new Folder via WebDAV, it shows as a normal folder and not a Document Set.  If I edit that folder's properties, I'm given the option to change the content type of the folder into a Document Set, but unfortunately this doesn't modify the behavior of the folder – to all intents and purposes it is still just a Folder despite having the other content type.

How can I prevent the use of Folders entirely in a Document Library?
Alternatively, is there any way for a Document Set to be the default in WebDAV?

Comment: What happens if you try the "List Settings > Advanced Settings" and set "Make "New Folder" command available?" to false?

Comment: That prevents creating folders in the SharePoint interface, but not in WebDAV.  (Aside: even if you use PowerShell to remove the Folder content type from that Doc Library, the "New Folder" button still works so Folders are clearly somehow "special" to SharePoint.)

Answer (score 2):

Great question. You may want to consider creating an event receiver that is triggered whenever an item is created. If the content-type is folder then delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote, care to provide feedback about what is incorrect?

Comment: Wasn't me who downvoted ... the solution sounds good to me but I'm not very familiar with event receivers.  Any good tips on getting started?  Also, would it be feasible to delete and automatically recreate as a Document Set?

Comment: Sorry to link to a generic Google search, but a search for 'develop sharepoint 2010 event receiver' returns many valid entries. You can do whatever you like from an event receiver. http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=en&nord=1&site=webhp&sa=X&ei=5N_fTdupHY-whAfL26y_Cg&ved=0CBcQBSgA&q=develop+sharepoint+2010+event+receiver&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=749b9b74a27a2bce&ion=1&biw=1061&bih=921

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a SharePoint designer workflow to handle this :

```
If Current Item:Content Type equals Folder
Delete item in Current Item
```

It deletes the folder as soon as it is created in Explorer View.

*Just make sure you set the workflow to run on Item Creation.*